# webpack dev server listening a file with extension PHP ( "index.php")

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

everybody.

I am using the default configuration, without any additional packages.

After a run of command, "npm run dev" have opened the file PHP like a page in the browser but file have downloaded.

How I can setting config, that dev server could be listening to a file with an extension of PHP?

Config:

```
    let path = require('path');

let conf = {
    entry: './panel/js/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join( __dirname, 'panel/js' ),
        publicPath: '/panel/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
      index: '',
      open: true,
      overlay: {
        warnings: true,
        errors: true
      },
      host: 'test.io',
      proxy: {
        '**': {
          target: 'https://test.io',
          changeOrigin: true,
        }
      }
    }
};

module.exports = conf;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "login-js.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --mode development --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --inline"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webpack DevServer is a simple http server, its purpose is to serve static files like html, css, js,  images... (unless you are using it as a middleware in a nodejs app)

Typically you have to use its `proxy` option described [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy), pointing to your `apache` or `nginx` server which normally runs your `php` based webapp.

**Edit based on your comments below**

First of all you should use the `.test` domain for your local development server. See [this article](https://webdevstudios.com/2017/12/12/google-chrome-63/). You can't use `test.io` as it is now in your code (test.io is an existing site on the web). First make the website you are developing accessible on `http://yoursitename.test` or `http://localhost` if you run only this one site. For this you need a webserver like `apache` or `nginx`. Webpack won't serve a `php` site for you, it's not for that...

You should also use a better directory structure for your application files. Here's an example for common usage:

```
├── src
  ├── js
  └── css
└── public
  ├── build
  └── images
```

Then your `webpack.config.js` could look something like this (using the above structure):

```
const path = require('path');
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

let conf = {
    mode: devMode ? "development" : "production",
    entry: {
        index: './src/js/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join( __dirname, 'public/build' ),
        publicPath: '/build/',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    devServer: {
      index: '',
      open: true,
      overlay: {
        warnings: true,
        errors: true
      },
      host: 'yoursitename.test',
      proxy: {
        '**': {
          target: 'http://yoursitename.test',
          changeOrigin: true,
        }
      }
    }
};

module.exports = conf;
```

Changes needed to your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --progress",
  "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --progress",
  "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --open"
}
```

**How to expand your knowledge**

I have to tell you that these things are the very basics of Webpack and if you still can't succeed to make your app work, you should read a lot of documentation and articles about Webpack (as I did when I was new to it).

[Start here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/) and go trough all the items on the left. [Guides](https://webpack.js.org/guides/) will provide you a lot of examples and [configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) will be useful when you know the basics well...

Comment: Thank's for the answer. Really I need your help. I tried but got an error.
code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! js@1.0.0 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config build/webpack.config.js`
pm ERR! Failed at the js@1.0.0 build script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\saini\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-15T18_10_37_259Z-debug.log

Comment: Do you have the ’cross-env’ package installed? If not, ’npm install cross-env --save-dev’ and try again.

Comment: Sorry, I see you have it included in your package.json.

Comment: I updated the config file. 
There is fixed problems but have got new )))
1. After when have opened the page in the browser, there have shown note: " Error occured while trying to proxy to: test.io:8080/ "
2. In the console of nodejs too have shown the messege "WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior
How could I be fixed the problems?
Biggest thanks for the help.

Comment: @Makhnov NP. But as it seems you're in the beginning stage with Webpack, I have totally reworked my original answer with new suggestions. If you like it please mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you and good luck!

Comment: Really thank's you for help. Everything is okay, there is work. P.S. I will learn more the webpack